# How to fill non column field of entity in room library

Tags: java, android, sqlite, android-room, android-architecture-components

I have a class entity as below

```
@Entity
public class Task {    
    private String name; 
    private Integer ParentId;
    private Integer userId;   
    @Ignore
    private int noOfSubTask;
}
```

in DAO class there is a method getTaskList()

```
@Dao
public interface TaskDao extends Dao<Task> {

@Query("SELECT *,(SELECT count(*) FROM Task b  WHERE a._id = b.ParentId ) AS noOfSubTask FROM Task a ")
LiveData<List<Task>> getTaskList();
}
```

I want to fill 
noOfSubTask with the number given by (SELECT count(*) FROM Task b  WHERE a._id = b.ParentId ) portion of query,
but problem is it is not a column so room library does not map it getTaskList method in dao implementation (auto-generated) class.

Is there any way to fill non column field of entity (like noOfSubTask in my case) using any method of dao class of room library?

Comment: which value you want to fill to it?

Comment: the value which is get from (SELECT count(*) FROM Task b  WHERE a._id = b.ParentId ) in the query

Comment: @Kevan Did the provided answer work for you? It doesn't seem to work for me...

Answer (score 14):

I faced the same problem a few days ago and had a look at this thread. I am using Kotlin `data` classes for creating database entities. Given that Kotlin data classes do not play well with inheritance subclassing was not a viable option. My solution was to use the `@Embedded` keyword in a wrapping class, as follows:

```
data class TaskToDisplay(@Embedded
                         var task: Task,
                         var noOfSubTask: Int = 0)
```

This solution does not create an additional column in the database and most importantly matches all Task's fields with Room's response columns.

Comment: This is amazing, using a wrapper separates out computed columns completely. In my case I needed them for matchinfo on full text search, but didn't want to go back to using a db cursor, thanks!

Answer (score 5):

Create a sub class of Task suppose

```
public class TaskDisplayModel extends Task{

@Ignore
private transient int noOfSubTask;

}
```

Then your query will be

```
@Query("SELECT *,(SELECT count(*) FROM Task b  WHERE a._id = b.ParentId ) AS noOfSubTask FROM Task a ")
LiveData<List<TaskDisplayModel >> getTaskList();
```

Comment: For me this only works if I get rid of the `@Ignore` annotation. I think as long as `TaskDisplayModel` isn't given to your database class as one of the entities to serialize, the `noOfSubTask` field won't be added to any database tables. Leaving `@Ignore` off also lets it be deserialized from the query results, which can either come directly from fields or be calculated. I also found the `transient` keyword to be unnecessary, but maybe it provides some benefit I'm unaware of.

Comment: Awesome! Works perfectly well without using `@Ignore` and `transient`.

Answer (score 4):

You should move the @Ignore field outside of the constructor, like this:

Sample data:

```
@Entity(primaryKeys = ["id"])
data class User(
    @SerializedName("id")
    val id: Int,

    @SerializedName("name")
    val name: String,

    @SerializedName("age")
    val age: Int
) {
   @Ignore
   val testme: String?
}
```

Refer [github discussion](https://github.com/googlesamples/android-architecture-components/issues/421) for more details

Answer (score 0):

I'm using Kotlin and I've had a similar problem, and below is how I solved it.

1. Add additional field **with ?(question mark)** for nullable, **without @Ignore annotation**

   ```
   @Entity(tableName = "task")
   data class Task (
       val name: String,
       val parentId: Integer,
       val userId: Integer,
       val noOfSubTask: Integer?
   )
   ```
2. Add additional field(noOfSubTask in this case) to every query that selects Task in DAO.

   ```
   @Dao
   interface TaskDao {
       @Query("SELECT *,(SELECT count(*) FROM Task b  WHERE a._id = b.ParentId ) AS noOfSubTask FROM Task a ")
       fun getTaskList(): LiveData<List<Task>>

       @Query("SELECT *, NULL AS noOfSubTask FROM Task WHERE name = :name")
       fun getTask(name: String): LiveData<Task>

       ...
   }
   ```

If this does not work, you can try [RawQuery](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/arch/persistence/room/RawQuery) that was recently introduced in Google I/O 2018.

Comment: This will create an additional column called noOfSubTask, that is not optimal

Comment: Yes, I also know that this workaround is not optimal and not clean. But at that time it was the only way I knew. There may have been a better solution now.

Comment: I gave a reply as I am also using Kotlin and data classes, please have a look as it might be useful to your project.

Comment: Okay, clean and optimized code is always right, but in some cases improving it to a certain level is also good for a healthier life. Happy coding!