# Room query with column alias returning null

Tags: android, android-room, android-architecture-components

I've been struggling with this and I haven't found a solution.

Let's say I have this sample entity:

```
@Entity (tableName="test")
public class Test{

    @PrimaryKey(autoGenerate = true)
    @ColumnInfo(name = "id")
    private long id;

    @ColumnInfo(name = "field1")
    @NonNull
    private double field1;

    @Ignore
    @ColumnInfo(name = "queryField")
    private transient String queryField;

}
```

So basically my table has `id` and `field1` while `queryField` is not a column table but it's used for instance on screens to show extra details from another table.

Then in my DAO

```
...
    @Query("Select a.id, a.field1, b.column as queryField
            "from test a inner join some_table on..." +
            "where a.id=:someId" +
            "order by i.name ASC")
    LiveData<List<Test>> get(long someId);
....
```

So running someting like this, and the query result while it contains test.id and test.field1 info it does not fill the queryField property which remains null.

`@Entity` does not allow this kind of queries? Do I need to generate another class to add the new column? I'd like to mix Entities and Pojos in the project to keep things simple.

Comment: tried to debug the generated code?

Comment: @pskink interestingly, looking into generated *DAO_impl.java I can see the generated code for my query but the cursor loop only uses the columns without `Ignore`, so the as queryField is not actually processed. Maybe @Ignore is not the right annotation for this?

Comment: I don't know, what if you remove that annotation?

Comment: Without `Ignore`  app crashes as it thinks that the new `queryField` should exist in database...

Comment: this could be helpful
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47282111/how-to-fill-non-column-field-of-entity-in-room-library